Adjusting kafka streams internal topics configuration from quarkus
I have a quarkus application running a kafka stream topology. This internally creates some internal kafka topics with the name app-KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000001-changelog. For this topic, I would like to adjust property max.message.bytes and so far after reading this kafka stream docu, I've tried with
quarkus.kafka-streams.topic.max.message.bytes=...
kafka-streams.topic.max.message.bytes=...

But seems not to be working. Is there a way to define this on the fly created topics with my own config?

The only way to make this work, was to re create the internal topics by applying a new name to application using prop quarkus.kafka-streams.application-id
